# How to display most used file (pdf, doc, docx, xls, …) into a browser by using PHP?

Tags: php, html, iframe

I need to display a (pdf,doc,docx,txt) documents inside an php web form with the ability to select a part of the document content and do some processing on it in the right click (like saving the selected content to DB)?

I try this way :-

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<?=urlencode($docx)?>&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

But is show me as `html`

Comment: I'm sure there are libraries for PHP to display all the file types you mention.

Comment: what is libraries  ?!!

Comment: @ZamalekMan try here for PHP libraries: https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php

Answer (score 0):

PHP can set the header information for a file and so you can display anything as file.php, loading the file.php  you can then specify what it should be handled as- for example you can generate an image and output it as a `jpeg` file :

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$img = LoadJpeg('bogus.image');
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php example.

Using a similar method for setting the header content-type you can output PDF contents or DOC or whatever, by setting the header to the correct file type and loading the contents of the file with PHPs `file_get_contents()` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php ) function, and outputting that to the browser / iframe.

Answer (score -1):

Two things you can do:

1. Just link to the .pdf/etc. location on your server
2. Save the image of it as a .jpg and display that then put a link to download the pdf/whatever

Comment: i donnt need to download file , only show it in my site

Comment: Yeah then it's just easier to use and image of it and just display that